# fetch data from 3rd party API - Single Responsibility Principle in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What's the most elegant way to fetch data from an external API if I want to be faithful to the Single Responsibility Principle? Where/when exactly should it be made?

Assuming I've got a `POST /foo` endpoint which after being called should somehow trigger a call to the external API and fetch/save some data from it in my local DB.
Should I add the call in the view? Or the Model?

Answer (score 0):

I usually add any external API calls into dedicated `services.py` module (same level as your `models.py` that you're planning to save results into or `common` app if any of the existing are not logically related)

Inside that module you can use class called smth like `MyExtarnalService` and add all needed methods for fetching, posting, removing etc. just like you would do with drf api view.

Also remember to handle exceptions properly (timeouts, connection errors, error response codes) by defining custom error exception classes.